# Node-Red POST multipart/form-data (http request)

Tags: node.js, httprequest, multipartform-data, node-red

I would like to POST two data in multipart / form-data format using Node-RED.
(One for text data, one for voice data)
I set the function node and http request node as follows, but it does not seem to be POST.

I think that it is necessary to create a multi-part body and assign it to msg.body, but I do not know how to create a multi-part body of the voice data.
I do not know how to solve it, so someone would like to tell me.

#### function node

```
var request = global.get('requestModule');
var fs = global.get('fsModule');
msg.body = {};
msg.body = {
    'apikey' : "**********",
    'wav' : fs.createReadStream('/tmp/testtest.wav')
};

msg.headers = {};
msg.headers['Content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';

return msg
```

#### http request(Property)

[image: http request node pic installed by default]

[image: http request node property pic]

method ⇒ POST
URL ⇒ https://xxxxyyyzzz/
SSL/TLS ⇒ No
Basic ⇒ No
Output ⇒ JSON

Comment: Is there a reason why you are writing code inside a `function` node, instead of just using the core `http request` node directly?

Comment: @SteveR Does the core http request node means node-red-contrib-http-request?  
If so, there is no place to enter the fie path and the api key.
Therefore, I write the code in the function node.

Comment: No, the core nodes do not start with `node-red-contrib-*` -- those are contributed by the community. The http request node is already installed with node-red, and does support posting multi part form data...

Comment: @SteveR Does  the core http request node indicate [http request node pic installed by default] shown in the above question?

Comment: Looks like the right one to me... From the node's info in the side bar, it looks like you will need to read the file contents into a `mg.payload`, move that into the msg body with a change node, and set the headers properly.

Comment: @SteveR Sorry, i can't understand. Can you tell me where you are saying? [http request node property pic]

Answer (score 3):

The `http request` Node-Red core node support `multipart/form-data` POST out of the box.

Add a `function` node before your `http request` with this Function :

```js
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
msg.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
msg.payload = {
    'apikey': msg.apiKey,
    'wav': {
        value: msg.payload.invoice.file,
        options: {
            filename: 'testtest.wav',
            contentType: 'audio/wav', // This is optionnal
        }
    }
}
return msg;
```

The `http request` node use `Request` nodejs library under the hood, and this one use `form-data` library for [handling multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads), so all the options supported by these works.

[The source code of the relevant part of `http request` handling multipart.](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/fad8dcd304728014551da41186d25db9f7320abd/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/nodes/core/network/21-httprequest.js#L220-L241)